# Azure DevOps queryByWiql does not query correct project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I would like to know if there is a way for the Azure DevOps dashboard widget to know what project it belongs to or resides in. For example, I have 2 projects. The widget should be able to differentiate between the two, fetch different data, but ultimately do the same thing.

I took a look at [the API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1?view=azure-devops#querybywiql())

Here is what I tried:

```
var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
var query = {
    query: "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Epic' AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Closed','Completed','Resolved','Removed', 'Done')"
};

witClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId).then(
    function (epics) {
      epics.workItems.forEach(epic => {
          ...
```

However, I am getting back Epics from projects that the dashboard is not under. Our org has several projects/products that have their own WorkItems.

I verified that the projectId variable maps to the correct project, I just don't know why my query returns Epics that do not belong to the correct project...

**I want to create a widget that determines which project it belongs to, and fetch data for only that project.**

Comment: Your query isn't limiting the results by project.

Comment: I just realized that now. However what is the use of the projectId and teamId parameters for the queryByWiql() then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to have the data of a specific project, be sure that you also refer to it in the WIQL query. You can do this by adding `[System.TeamProject] = @project` to your query.

```
var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
var query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Epic' AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Closed','Completed','Resolved','Removed', 'Done') AND [System.TeamProject] = @project";

witClient.queryByWiql({ query: query }, projectId).then(function (epics) {
    // do your stuff here
});
```